# Odoo 14 Invoice creation issues - does not apply taxes

Tags: odoo, invoice, tax

I'm trying to create an invoice using the request below.
Q#1 Although I can see an invoice getting created on Odoo, the taxes are not applied.
I can see that :

1. the product from invoice line has taxes on it
2. the fiscal position is configured correctly with the same tax applied

When I try to create an invoice manually, the tax is getting applied.

Q#2 Although I send 2 invoice lines, only 1 appears on Odoo

Q#3 Although discount_fixed is seen on the model, I only see % discount on Odoo invoice

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": "",
"method": "call",
"params": {
    "service": "object",
    "method": "execute",
    "args": [
        "{{databaseName}}",
        {{userId}},
        "{{password}}",
        "account.move",
        "create",
        {
            "name": "Test Create Invoice 1",
            "state": "draft",
            "currency_id": 2,
            "create_uid": {{userId}},
            "partner_id": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "journal_id": 1,
            "fiscal_position_id":1,
            "invoice_date": "2022-01-27",
            "invoice_date_due": "2022-05-27",
            "move_type": "out_invoice",
            "type_name": "Invoice",
            "invoice_line_ids": [[0, "_", {
                "sequence": 1,
                "product_id": 1,
                "company_id": 1,
                "account_id": 1,
                "analytic_account_id": 1,
                "analytic_segment_one_id": 1,
                "name": "Test Invoice Line",
                "quantity": 1,
                "price_unit": 50,
                "discount_fixed": 10
            }],[0, "_", {
                "sequence": 2,
                "product_id": 2,
                "company_id": 1,
                "account_id": 2,
                "analytic_account_id": 2,
                "analytic_segment_one_id": 2,
                "name": "Test Invoice Line",
                "quantity": 2,
                "price_unit": 10,
                "discount_fixed": 10
            }]]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A#1: `onchange('product_id')` method apply taxes, I recommends you to create your own method in order to achieve this behaviour: Create in memory invoice, call `onchange` and then `create`.

A#2: You sould sent a list of dict, every element its and invoice.

A#3: The A#1 could help you here too.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: To get a detailed answer for every question you should create a separated post for every one.